# ** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :epipe,

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I am trying out Crawly with this tutorial https://hexdocs.pm/crawly/tutorial.html

I add the needed dependencies

```
 defp deps do
  [
    {:crawly, "~> 0.13.0"},
    {:floki, "~> 0.26.0"}
  ]
end
```

I run `mix deps.get`
and add the spider:

```
defmodule Homebase do
  use Crawly.Spider

  @impl Crawly.Spider
  def base_url(), do: "https://www.homebase.co.uk"

  @impl Crawly.Spider
  def init() do
    [
      start_urls: [
        "https://www.homebase.co.uk/our-range/tools"
      ]
    ]
  end

  @impl Crawly.Spider
  def parse_item(_response) do
    %Crawly.ParsedItem{:items => [], :requests => []}
  end
end
```

I run `iex -S mix` and get the following error:

`** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :epipe, "/home/niki/.mix/rebar3 bare compile --paths /home/niki/projects/first-crawler/crawler2/spiderman/_build/dev/lib/*/ebin" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile epipe", update it with "mix deps.update epipe" or clean it with "mix deps.clean epipe"`

I have tried the recommended solutuions by the output but nothing works.

edit: this is the output of `mix deps.compile`:[image]

EDIT: I installed `kiex` and switched to version 1.10. That fixed tha peoblem

Comment: I could not reproduce it. What OS are you using?

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Show the full output of `mix deps.compile epipe` please.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `deps/`, `_build/` directories as well as your local hex cache (usually at `~/.hex/`)?  Try that, then re-install and re-compile.

Comment: @Everett i tried that and it gives the same error when re-compiling

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin i added the output as a picture

Comment: if you are using OTP-24, downgrade to OTP-23 and try again

Answer (score 0):

I installed kiex and switched to version 1.10. That fixed tha peoblem